# The Osmnx python graph_to_gdfs sometimes returns a list in the name column, what's causing this?

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm using OSmnx to create some nice maps where I color streets based on the name of the street, inspired by puntofisso (eg: if it's a street, it needs to be red, a lane is green, etc). I noticed that sometimes the name of an edge is not a string, but a list instead. I worked around that so far, but is there an argument that could solve this? Or is it caused by something in OpenStreetMap? I was unsuccessful in googling for answers unfortunately.

```
test_place='Kerkstraat, Delft'
# Create a graph around this address
G3 = ox.graph_from_address(test_place, network_type='all',dist=100, dist_type='bbox')
edge_attributes3 = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G3, nodes=False)
edge_attributes3.head(50)
```

This gives [Markt, Kerkstraat] in the name column in the row with index 2.
My solution now just takes the first element of the list, but I wanted to find the Kerkstraat in Delft and it turns out that the Kerkstraat only occurs in edges that have a list for their name.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the arguments you passed to `graph_from_address`, you've left the `simplify=True` default parameterization. Therefore your graph [was simplified](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_address) when created. From [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph) on simplification:

> Some of the resulting consolidated edges may comprise multiple OSM ways, and if so, their multiple attribute values are stored as a list.

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it, thanks! Thought I tried to change simplify parameter but I probably only tried simplify=True (which I see now is the default..)